# Using the ably flutter package, how can I subscribe to and listen to an event in Laravel and Flutter?

Tags: laravel, flutter, dart, chat, ably-realtime

I'm developing a chat application using Laravel and flutter. I'm using ably_flutter package to make it realtime. The channel is created successfully but it's faild to listen an event or a message.

```
final clientOptions = ably.ClientOptions( 
      key: 'rVPjew.ydfBPA:JqRRY9JI49_L9l8CsfvMxXuxhMeyQzgEo6apWE');

 subscribeAbly() async {
    ably.Realtime realtime = ably.Realtime(options: clientOptions);

    realtime.connection
        .on(ably.ConnectionEvent.connected)
        .listen((ably.ConnectionStateChange stateChange) async {
print(stateChange.current)// connected
      ably.RealtimeChannel channel = realtime.channels.get('public.room');
      channel.subscribe(name: 'message.new').listen((ably.Message message) {
        print("message is fired");//it's not working
        final data = jsonEncode(message.data);
        final response = jsonDecode(data)['message'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
        setState(() {
          mapData.insert(0, {"message": "From ably", "is_sender": false});
        });
      });
    });

   @override
   initState(){
   super.initState();
    subscribeAbly()
 }
```

I'm using Flutter 2.8 and ably_flutter 1.2.15
Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As a debugging step, if you publish a message from within flutter to this channel using `channel.publish()` do you receive an event?

If not then something might be wrong with your setup in Flutter. One thing I'd try would be to move the `realtime` object declaration outside of the async function scope and make it a property instead.

Other than that - again as a debugging step try to subscribe to all events on the channel:

```
channel.subscribe()
```

instead of:

```
channel.subscribe(name: 'message.new')
```

and double check if the channel name is correct and you've set up Laravel to publish messages to the same channel:

```
realtime.channels.get('public.room')
```

Could you also please elaborate on how you are publishing messages on the laravel side?

Comment: Yes, I receive an event when I publish through the channel.publish(). The laravel side looks like this https://github.com/Getaye-Biaznlgn/ably_test

Comment: Hey @Getaye, it looks like you're trying to use ably-flutter with the laravel broadcasting feature. Currently laravel broadcasting is designed to work with the laravel-echo JavaScript client, so I don't think there's an officially supported way to achieve this. I think your best bet is to use the [ably-php-laravel](https://github.com/ably/ably-php-laravel) library directly in your laravel application.